# What is the star (*) doing in this FizzBuzz solution?

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

Learning programming in Python and I am doing some challenges. I've run into something I haven't learned yet and was curious what this code is doing.

So my challenge is called the "FizzBuzz" challenge. The instructions are simple:

> Create a function that takes a number as an argument and returns
>   "Fizz", "Buzz" or "FizzBuzz".
>
> If the number is a multiple of 3 the output should be "Fizz". If the
>   number given is a multiple of 5, the output should be "Buzz". If the
>   number given is a multiple of both 3 and 5, the output should be
>   "FizzBuzz". If the number is not a multiple of either 3 or 5, the
>   number should be output on its own.

I wrote this code to solve it (obviously it can be better):

```
def fizz_buzz(num):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
        return 'FizzBuzz'
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        return 'Fizz'
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        return 'Buzz'
    else:
        return str(num)
```

But, once I submitted my solution I was able to see the top solution, which is:

```
def fizz_buzz(num):
    return "Fizz"*(num%3==0) + "Buzz"*(num%5==0) or str(num)
```

My question is what is the * doing here? Can someone point me to documentation or resources that addresses what this persons code has done? I don't find it super readable but it is apparently the best solution to the problem.

Comment: Looks to be multiplying "Fizz" or "Buzz" times 1 or 0 (true or false) to determine whether to output it or not.

Comment: `or` with two strings returns the first if it's not empty, or the second if it is empty

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but this is a good question otherwise, so I've removed that part from the title. I also made the title more specific while I was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, shorter doesn't always mean better. In this case, your solution is fine, and the "top solution" is clever, but needlessly confusing, as you're aware :P

The star is doing string multiplication, and it's exploiting the fact that `False == 0` and `True == 1`. So if `num` is divisible by 3, you get `'Fizz'` once, and if `num` is divisible by 5, you get `'Buzz'` once. Otherwise you get an empty string, `''`, and because an empty string is falsy, the `or` clause means it will be replaced by `str(num)`.

Answer (score 4):

`bool` in Python is a subclass of `int`; `True` has the value `1`, `False`, `0`.

Sequences (including `str`) in Python can be multiplied, to get the sequence repeated that many times, so:

```
"Fizz"*(num%3==0)
```

multiplies `"Fizz"` by `1` (numeric value of `True`) when `num % 3 == 0`, producing the original string, and by `0` (numeric value of `False`) otherwise, producing the empty string.

The same work is done with `"Buzz"` and concatenated. If both of them produced the empty string (which is falsy), then the `or` means `str(num)` is evaluated and returned (Python's `or` and `and` don't evaluate to strict `True` or `False`, they evaluate to the last item evaluated, and short-circuit, so `or` always evaluates to the first truthy item, or the last item in the `or` chain regardless of truthiness).

Comment: Alright, so broken down:

```
"Fizz"*(num%3==0)  
```
This isn't num%==3 * fizz, right? It's more like the format of a comprehension and I'm assuming the *(whatever) is the way you do this? Or, is it literally multiplying?
```
+ "Buzz"*(num%5==0)
```
Same thing as Fizz but I understand the + between them.
```
or str(num)
```
Now, if I understand you then if this function was passed and not a multiple of 3 or 5 then the **or str(num)** will be true?

Comment: @sdiggles: There is literal multiplication going on (with sequences, including `str`, it performs repetition; repeating zero times means "get empty version of sequence"), either `"Fizz" * True` or `"Fizz" * False`, where `True == 1` and `False == 0`. `+` on sequences means concatenation. `or str(num)` need not be true or false (although it always will be true since it numbers converted to `str` produce non-empty `str`, which are always true). If the part before the `or` is falsy, then the part after is the result of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` is string multiplication as usual. It's just multiplying by `0` or `1` based on whether the condition to print the phrase is met. If neither condition is met, it defaults to returning the number, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a resource, but I can tell you what it does. The phrase `num%3==0` is a Boolean which is true if the number is divisible by 3. If that's the case, this phrase returns a 1 (or 0 if False). Same for `num%5==0` and divisible by 5. This is then being multiplied by the string `Fizz` and/or `Buzz` and concatenated together, where multiplying by 1 returns the string and 0 nothing. If neither of those holds, it returns `str(num)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the link to any documentation or resource about it, but I can explain it to you.

Firstly in python `str` can be multiplied by a number, for instance `'Fizz' * 3` will return `'FizzFizzFizz'` or `'Fizz' * 0` will return `''`, an empty string.

Secondly `bool` in python can be also recognized as `int`, i.e. `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

Thirdly in python strings can be added e.g. `'Fizz'+'Buzz'` will return `'FizzBuzz'`

What the best solution guy does is very simple by `num%3==0` he gets `bool` and just multiplies the `str` 'Fizz' or 'Buzz' by it and returns.